# Summing a column in a table in Meteor

Tags: meteor

If I create a table in a Template, is there a way to add a row of "reactive totals" at the bottom of the table using Meteor?  Or do I have to write the code to sum the columns, the same way I would in ordinary JavaScript?

For example, given the table...

```
State   Sales
NY      1234
FL       670
TX      2306
Total   4210
```

Can I use some reactive technique to calculate and keep the Total cell showing `4210` up-to-date as other cells change?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to use [MongoDB $sum aggregator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

Taking Erik Johnson's example, you need to do this:

```
// HTML

<div id="allSales">
  <h2><span>Total sales: </span>{{allSales}}</h2>
</div>

// JS

Template.templatename.helpers({    
  allSales: function() {
    var allSales =  allStates.aggregate( [ { $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: "$sales" } } } ]);
    return allSales.total;

  },
});
```

Comment: Does this involve a trip to the server, or does it happen on the client?

Comment: I thought aggregates didn't work in meteor, except on the server side with a special library

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it - I'm sure there's probably an easier way, but I'm still a beginner at Meteor:

```
// HTML

<div id="allSales">
  <h2><span>Total sales: </span>{{allSales}}</h2>
</div>

// JS

Template.templatename.helpers({    
  allSales: function() {
    var allStates = Statescollection.find();
    var mappedItems = allStates.map((function(allStates) {return allStates.sales;}));
    var allSales = _.reduce(mappedItems, function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0);
    return allSales;
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and have found the following solution for both columns and rows of a table

[In Meteor, how can i do a sum of some computed fields in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021574)

Answer (score 0):

I've created the package [peppelg:mongo-sum](https://atmospherejs.com/peppelg/mongo-sum). With it, `MyCollection.find().sum('field')` will return the sum of all the values in the field `'field'`.