# In Meteor, how can I do a sum of some computed fields in a table?

Tags: jquery, meteor, html-table

I have completely rewritten this question, because I have made some headway, and I also needed to clarify it further.

In general - I'd like to calculate row and column totals for a table, without having to recalculate each cell value twice. Let me explain.

I have a collection and each doc contains 12 values. For each doc, I need to perform two slow expensive calculations on these 12 doc values producing two results and then display these two results in a table. 
Then I also need the sum of the two computed results on each row, and a sum of all the computed results for each column.

The page would look like this:

```
resa    resb    row1sum
resa    resb    row2sum
(etc)
col1sum col2sum
```

And a portion of the template might look like this:

```
<table>
{{#each docs}}
  <tr><td>{{resa}}</td> <td>{{resb}}</td> <td>{{rowsum}}</td></tr>
{{/each}}
<tr><td>{{colsum1}}</td> <td>{{colsum2}}</td>
</table>
```

For each row, I am now using a transform clause in my cursor helper to generate the results and rowsums.

```
docs: function() {

return myCollection.find({},{transform: function(doc) {
  var resa = slowcalculation1(doc);
  doc.resa = resa;
  var resb = slowcalculation2(doc);
  doc.resb = resb;
  doc.rowsum = resa+resb;
  return doc;
  }
});

},
```

This works well to calculate the two results and rowsum for each doc and is reactive.

But I am now trying to find a way to efficiently calculate the column sums.

I could use the following

```
Tracker:autorun(function()
{
  var col1tot=0;
  var col2tot=0;
  myCollection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var resa = slowcalculation1(doc);
    col1tot += resa;
    var resb = slowcalculation2(doc);
    col2tot += resb;
    });
  Session.set('col1',col1tot);
  Session.set('col2',col2tot);
  // then get these coltotals using helpers
});
```

But is there a better way? As it stands, to generate the page, I am calling slowcalculations() twice for each cell, and I like to only calculate each cell value once, since my calculations are, ahem, slow. :)

Can I instead, somehow, calculate the column sums, but within in my cursor helper?

Or is there some other way to reactively take the whole collection and reactively generate both the rowsums and colsums in a single pass?

Comment: Reactively available across your app? or just updating in this single view?

Comment: Just the single view

Comment: I forgot to ask, do the vals update reactively? otherwise just use jQuery to sum the rows and columns on template render.

Comment: yes, the vals update reactively. for each doc in a collection I process numerous fields to generate the page containing the table with val1 val2 val3 and vall4. Then somehow after val1 and val2 change reactively, I like the sums to be recomputed computed from the vals.

Comment: Ok, this is tricky... I have not yet found a good pattern for this situation. The problem is that the DOM will mutate as the helpers reactively update the rows and column vals. Tracking this change is difficult, I've got a couple of hacky solutions. I think the proper way is to somehow use ReactiveVar for the Tracker, but I never was able to get those to work.

Another simple method that might work is to simply create a helper for the row and column totals, which use the same logic (or shared function) of the val helpers.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Your suggestion using the val helper functions is how I am doing it now, but since the calcs on the vals are slow, the totals are even slower. Its doing a lot of work just to do a few sums :(

Comment: The best solution I have so far for total is to scan the original source documents as I did for the vals (to setup the autorun), but ignore what I read, and use jquery to sum the vals instead. Not particularly elegant unfortunately.

Comment: Could you use a Session variable or a dedicated Collection perhaps? The sneaky trick I came up with is to make a dedicated single document 'Invalidator' collection, which when I want to trigger a template re-render I simply update the value in this doc. To get the template to re-render when this changes I Invalidator.findOne() in the template router data context. It's hacky, but it works. This would then re-trigger the template render code, your jquery sums.

Comment: How is this question different from your last one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001791/in-meteor-is-it-possible-to-flush-per-row-of-a-table

Comment: Show your current implementation in the question itself, not in the comments. And I have already commented in your last question. Use `Tracker.autorun()`, this does not scan - that's not how Tracker works. It does not scan. But as I said, show us your implementation.

Comment: Thanks dayuloli. The problem is that I don't know how to read the vals without recomputing them, so I can sum them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I believe I have an answer. It seems to work, at least.

I have modified my template helper that is passed to the template and it now looks like this

```
docs: function() {

var col1sum=0;
var col2sum=0; 

return myCollection.find({},{transform: function(doc) {
  var resa = slowcalculation1(doc);
  doc.resa = resa;
  var resb = slowcalculation2(doc);
  doc.resb = resb;
  doc.rowsum = resa+resb; // the rowsum

  col1sum += resa;
  col2sum += resb;
  Session.set('col1sum',col1sum);
  Session.set('col2sum',col2sum);
  // then get these colsums into template using helpers

  return doc;
  }
});

},
```

This calcs the row sums, and the column sums, minimizing the number of times slowcalculations() are done.